# Macro Substitution In SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to I transpose a string that holds a mathematical formula into the result.

For Eg:

declare @@question as nvarchar(50)

set @@question='2+2+2+2+2'

select ' The Answer to ' + @@Question + ' is ' (the result of @@question)

Comment: What is the source of these expressions? If it is untrusted input you are open to SQL injection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dynamic SQL:

```
declare @question as nvarchar(50);
declare @result int;
declare @sql nvarchar(max);

set @question = '2+2+2+2+2';

set @sql = 'select @result = ' + @question;

exec sp_executesql @sql,
     N'@result int output',
     @result = @result output;

select @result;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/26930) is a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: hoping I don't have to create a new thread, I thought the question i asked would direct me to solving my task. Basically the 2+2+2+2 questions are stored in a table, and the + signs are commas.... so I used your solution to do this, but it ain't working.... any ideas?    
 declare com1 as nvarchar(100)
declare com as nvarchar(100)
set com= 'select replace(class_historyTY,'','',''+'') from #aety1'

set com1 ='exec sp_executesql  com'
exec sp_executesql com1
@gordon Linoff

Comment: @user9930055 . . . You should ask another question if the string is stored in a table.  This question is about a constant string and it has been answered.